# Getting a comma-delimited list of PK's for duplicates of a record in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, csv

This is an off-shoot of a previous question I had: [A little fuzzy on getting DISTINCT on one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544314/a-little-fuzzy-on-getting-distinct-on-one-column)

This query makes a little more sense, given the data:

```
SELECT     Receipts.ReceiptID, FolderLink.ReceiptFolderID
FROM         dbo.tbl_ReceiptFolderLnk AS FolderLink INNER JOIN
             dbo.tbl_Receipt AS Receipts ON FolderLink.ReceiptID = Receipts.ReceiptID
```

With results:

```
ReceiptID            ReceiptFolderID       NewColumn (duplicate folder ID list)
-------------------- ---------------      ----------
1                    3
2                    3
3                    7
4     <--->          4                       8,9
5                    4
6                    1
3                    8
4     <--->          8                       4,9
4     <--->          9                       4,8
```

That answer provided me to view distinct(ReceiptID)'s... great.  Now, for those ID's, 3 and 4, they exist in multiple ReceiptFolderID's.

Given this NON-unique list of ReceiptID's, I'd like an additional column, of comma-delimited ReceiptFolderLinkID's where the ReceiptID also exists.

So for ReceiptID=4, the new column, say, DuplicateFoldersList, should read, "8,9", etc, and similar with ID=3, or any other duplicates.

So basically, I'd like another column to indicate the ReceiptFolderID's additional occurrences of ReceiptID in other folders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that, given a ReceiptID and the "current" ReceiptFolderID for that row, returns the other ReceiptFolderIDs as a concatenated, comma-delimited list. Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOtherReceiptFolderIDs](@receiptID int, @receiptFolderID int)
RETURNS varchar(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue varchar(MAX)

    SELECT   @returnValue = COALESCE(@returnValue + ', ', '') + COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(MAX), ReceiptFolderID), '')
    FROM     tbl_ReceiptFolderLink AS FolderLink
    WHERE    FolderLink.ReceiptID = @receiptID
    AND      FolderLink.ReceiptFolderID <> @receiptFolderID

    RETURN @returnValue
END
```

Then, you can run a query that uses this function to obtain your new column:

```
SELECT      Receipts.ReceiptID, ReceiptFolderID, dbo.GetOtherReceiptFolderIDs(Receipts.ReceiptID, ReceiptFolderID) AS NewColumn
FROM        tbl_Receipt AS Receipts
INNER JOIN  tbl_ReceiptFolderLink AS FolderLinks
ON          Receipts.ReceiptID = FolderLinks.ReceiptID
```

I tested this and it produces the following results (if I got your schema correctly):

```
ReceiptID    ReceiptFolderID    NewColumn
6            1                  NULL
1            3                  NULL
2            3                  NULL
4            4                  8, 9
5            4                  NULL
3            7                  8
3            8                  7
4            8                  4, 9
4            9                  4, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql there is group_concat aggregate function, but in T-SQL and oracle you need to use another approach... [This site](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) lists multiple approaches for T-SQL, but none are very simple and easy (as mysql is)